# How do I set properties on file creation using Subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

How do I configure Subclipse so that when I create a `*.java` file certain Subversion properties will be set by default such as `svn:keywords` or `svn:eol-style`? I've been digging through my options and google and can't seem to locate the answer. I know its possible since I use to have it set up that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Subversion feature.  You need to configure auto-props.  If you are using SVN 1.7 or older read this:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto

IF you are using SVN 1.8 (Subclipse 1.10) there is a new/easier way to do it.  See here:

http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/the-road-to-repository-dictated-configuration-day-2-autoprops

Once this is configured, these properties will be added automatically as files are "added" to Subversion.

Comment: That would explain why I couldn't find the "feature". :P Thanks!